# Does this cable support 1440p/2k 144Hz?

Tags: macbook-pro, displayport

I would like to connect an external monitor (1440p/2k 144Hz) to my Macbook Air M1.
My monitor has Mini displayport and HDMI outputs.
Does this cable support 144Hz on 2k? https://www.apple.com/shop/product/HN8B2ZM/A/mophie-usb-c-cable-with-mini-displayport-connector
Or can I use an adapter instead of this cable?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That cable is marketed as supporting "4K and 5K external monitor[s] with pixel-perfect clarity", which implies that it's at least a [Standard DisplayPort cable that supports HBR2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Cable_bandwidth_and_certifications), capable of up to 4K 60 Hz. Furthermore, [cables that carry a DisplayPort Alt Mode over USB-C signal support HBR3](https://www.anandtech.com/show/12216/vesa-announces-dp8k-certified-displayport-cables), meaning it can support 5K 60 Hz all the way up to 8K 60 Hz.

At 1440p, standard DisplayPort cables of HBR2 spec can carry up to 165 Hz signal. HBR3 increases that to 240 Hz.